# Loadrunner JMS message (Queue to Topic)

Tags: loadrunner

Have a situation in a Tibco EAI world, where the message (Soap/ JMS) is sent on a queue and the message finally comes back through a topic.

1. Point to Point scenarios work easily via Loadrunner provided JMS API functions
2. In this scenario (Publish-Subscribe), have a situation where Input Message (Queue) -----> Output message (Topic), you cannot cast topic to a queue 
   jms_set_message_property("JMSReplyTo","JMSReplyTo", "**TopicName**");
   jms_send_message_queue ("Send the JMS message...");

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsFederatedTopic cannot be cast to javax.jms.Queue
    at com.mercury.ws.jms.SessionManagerImpl.getQueue(SessionManagerImpl.java:94)
    at com.mercury.ws.jms.JMSSupportImpl.sendMessageQueue(JMSSupportImpl.java:100)
    at com.mercury.ws.jms.JMSBridge.send_message_queue(JMSBridge.java:43)
Script.c(98): Error:JMS call execution failed

Thinking of considering to do this as a Java Vuser. Has anyone seen this situation before? Any clues appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Java Vuser is the way I chose. Started with an Eclipse project and looks good:
Steps:

1. Used a template from http://www.myloadtest.com/soap-over-jms-with-loadrunner/
   (Thanks to Stuart)
2. Note that the template uses P2P communication (Q to Q)
3. In my scenario, it's a Pub-Sub and the destination is a topic
4. Hence, I need to set-up 2 connections (one for a Queue to send the message and the other for Topic to subscribe to the messages)
5. The message needs to undergo Bytes conversion in UTF-8 and getBytes("UTF-8") did the job
6. Imp: Talk to Developers on which are the crucial JMS headers and set them appropriately before sending the JMS message

Onto Loadrunner JavaVuser from Eclipse now..

Answer (score 0):

I typically do queues as a Java Virtual User rather than dealing with the mysticism of the JMS Web Services Interface, but occasionally (with MQ) I will do them as a Winsock Virtual User because it is a bit faster for me to work with Sockets than it is to think in C and transpose to Java.

(I am a native functional 'C' Programmer)